# Play music to bluetooth, but system sounds to internal speakers

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, bluetooth

When I connect my Bluetooth speakers, all audio goes to bluetooth.

I would like only music to be routed to the bluetooth speakers, but all other audio from the system (alarms, skype, audio in firefox, whatever...) to still be played through the computer's internal speakers.

Is this possible?

(I currently have Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, and my usual music player is gmusicbrowser)

As requested in the comments, here are the (very normal) sound settings, which don't seem to have any fine-grained routing options, only application muting/volume:

[image: Sound Output settings]

[image: Sound Applications settings]

Comment: Please, provide us with the screenshots of your system sound settings.

Comment: @IDvoretskyi : done, though it's just the standard Ubuntu Sound panel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is, through [pavucontrol](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/pavucontrol/).

In fact, that's my configuration too.

Spotify goes to <kbd>CSL-27998</kbd> (my Bluetooth adapter) and everything else goes to the Internal Stereo (because this is the one selected in the screen you posted).

[image: pavucontrol]

EDIT: This is my configuration on the Sound System Setting

[image: Sound system Settings]

Please also note that when you modify the settings in the System Setting (second screenshot) it resets what you did in pavucontrol (because it's more coarse) and redirects everything to the output you choose.

Comment: Well, it sort-of-works, thanks to pavucontrol. Though in practice, it doesn't work for me or not with gmusicbrowser. The Sound settings need to be on internal speakers, so that's where everything goes, except what has been configured in pavucontrol to go to BT. However, when gmusicbrowser switches to the next song, it goes back to the default internal speakers! The pavucontrol setting remains only for the duration of a single track.